# Different Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragment

My main question is, what's the correct way to supply different Fragments to the FragmentPagerAdapter that I have implemented. For example, I am currently doing this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return(3);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return Fragment2.newInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return Fragment3.newInstance(position);
    }
    return Fragment1.newInstance(position);  
}
```

Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls Try this way...

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return Fragment2.newInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return Fragment3.newInstance(position);
    }
    return null;  // <-----  I think you have to change here...
}
```